# Symfony2 : login_check and annotation

Tags: symfony, authentication, annotations

In my symfony project, I would like to use authentification.
So I wrote this in my security.yml file

```
 firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        default:
            anonymous: ~

        login_firewall:
          pattern:    ^/login$
          anonymous:  ~

        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path:  /login
                check_path:  /login_check
                post_only: true
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                default_target_path:      /
                use_referer:          false
                username_parameter:       username
                password_parameter:       password
                intention:            authenticate
            logout:
                path:  /logout
                target: /
```

Ok, now documentation says that I need to add in routing.yml this :

```
login:
    pattern:   /login
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeSecurityBundle:Security:login }
login_check:
    pattern:   /login_check
```

But I am using annotation, so I don't use routing files. Instead I have this :

```
    /**
     * @Route("/login")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function loginAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $session = $request->getSession();

        // get the login error if there is one
        if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
          $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        } else {
          $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
          $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        }

        return array(
          // last username entered by the user
          'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
          'error'     => $error,
        );
    }
```

If I do nothing, I have an error in my login page :

```
 "Unable to generate a URL for the named route "login_check" as such route does not exist."
```

If I add an action in my controller with an empty response, there is... nothing.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`login_check` or whatever you specify is system defined route and not an action. That means that you can not/shall not/will not define it manually in controller. ;)

I myself use `annotations` to do routing but, one way or another, you will use `routing.yml` in order to import your controllers and thus annotated routes from within them.

So, go ahead, just define that route in your `routing.yml` and it should work.

Comment: When I do this, I have this error :  
Unable to find the controller for path "/login_check". Maybe you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration?

Comment: The one that says `Unable to generate a URL`, right? Could it be the conflict between firewalls? I see that you also have `login_firewall` which I think overlaps with `secured_area` firewall